# How do I rename or edit the SVC file of a WCF service in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wcf

This one is driving me crazy!

I've just upgraded to VS2010 beta 2 and created a simple WCF service. In previous VS versions I could easily find and edit the name and contents of the SVC file from the default Service1.svc to whatever I wanted to (i.e. e.g. MyTestWCFService.svc). I'm trying to do this in VS2010 but;

1) Can't find the svc file to edit anywhere, or

2) Can't find any option to specify what the url filename (svc) should actually be.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you create the WCF service project? Did you do a new "WCF Service Application" under the "Web" templates or did you use the "WCF Service Library" under "WCF" templates? If you use the "WCF Service Application" template you will get an .svc created for you because it knows you intend to host in ASP.NET/IIS. If you just use "WCF Service Library" it doesn't know how you intend to host it, so it's all about contracts and implementation, but no hosting files.